# Keep selected pages from PDF

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, pypdf

I have a pandas dataframe, pdf_summary, which is sorted and has 50 unique rows. Each row is a particular combination of file_pages. How could I create a folder and PDF for each file_name?

```
pdf_path = "Documents/menu.pdf"
```

```
pdf_summary

            file_name             file_pages_to_keep
  1 - Monday, Wednesday                1,3
  2 - Monday                            1
  3 - Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday       1,2,3
...
  50 - Friday                           5
```

The expected output would be 50 folders, with one PDF inside each folder with only those file_pages taken from the `menu.pdf`.

```
"Documents/1 - Monday, Wednesday/1 - Monday, Wednesday.pdf" (PDF only has pages 1 and 3 from menu.pdf)
...
```

Comment: What did you try so far, where is the question? Please do not expect SO to be a coding service for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you define a function for writing a pdf into a folder that allows you to select the pages:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def extract_pages(input_pdf, output_pdf, pages):
    with open(input_pdf, "rb") as file:
        reader = PdfReader(file)
        writer = PdfWriter()
        for page_num in pages:
            writer.add_page(reader.pages[page_num - 1])  # Page numbers start from 0
        with open(output_pdf, "wb") as output_file:
            writer.write(output_file)
```

Then you iterate over the rows of your df and for every row, you store the name of the pdf file (based on the file_name column) and the pages that you have to write:

```
for index, row in pdf_summary.iterrows():
    # Create a folder with the file_name if it doesn't exist
    folder_name = row['file_name']
    folder_path = os.path.join("output_folders", folder_name)
    os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)

    # Extract pages to keep from the PDF
    file_pages_to_keep = [int(page) for page in row['file_pages_to_keep'].split(',')]
    output_pdf_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f"{folder_name}.pdf")

    # Create a new PDF with the specified pages
    extract_pages(pdf_path, output_pdf_path, file_pages_to_keep)
```

Comment: when running the code a second time, is there a way to erase all the previous pdfs made?

Comment: just add a `if os.path.exists(output_pdf): os.remove(output_pdf)` just after the definition of the function

Comment: is it possible to create a version where all pdf files are saved in just 1 folder?

Comment: Yes that's quite easy, you just create a dir outside the for cycle, so basically you move the first 3 line of code in the for outside the for, and you just choose the name you prefer in the `folder_name` like so: `folder_name  = 'name'`, then you keep only from `file_pages_to_keep ` in the for cycle and that's it